# Spreadsheets API - appending values when the spreadsheet has formulas in some columns

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am using the spreadsheets api to append values to a sheet but this sheet has a particularity, it has some columns with formulas that procces the data that i am supposed to introduce in the other columns, so i can´t erase this columns, but when i try to append a value the value is appended at the end, where the formula is not defined, e.i the columns with formulas are making my code to skip the rows until there is no formula , this is a piece of the code i am using to append

```
import os
import pickle
import os.path
import io
import shutil

from lector_nombre import lectorNombre
from Tablas import lectorTablas
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

#SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0ew23gmUUqptlb23frvfvE2upms'
#SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'

"""Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
"""
creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()

data=[["data","data","data","data","https://google.com"]]
res = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId="134542fvbvfdfewdvwed4",
                            range="sheet!A1:G1",
                            valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
                            insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",
                            body={"values":data}).execute()
print(res)
```

and here there is a image of how my sheet looks[image]

EDIT:

i think i am not being really clear with my question,what i really need is to specify a range that let me write where i want without skipping the rows by the blame of the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [appending values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values) using  [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) you are basically adding a new row and set its data.

What you need is to use [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update), which lets you modify values in a range of a spreadsheet without adding new rows or columns.

**Example:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer is just that the spreadsheet have old data and i don´t want to specify the range every time i need to run the code i just want the new data to be filled below the old data without skippinig for the blame of te formula column

Comment: I understand your concern but based on the documents there are only 2 options in setting values in the spreadsheet which is either update() or append(). What you want is not possible for append() since it will always look for the last table which is the end of your formula column. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)

Comment: One workaround i could think of is to remove the formula first, and just add an apps script with onOpen() trigger that will add formulas to the non-empty row with empty formula column. By that you can use append() to append data (without formula column) and let the apps script update the sheet by adding the formula

Comment: so what you mean is like going to the spreadsheets UI and drag the cell formula but doing it with appscript? also i can use appscript with my current code? thanks you a lot!

Comment: could you please send me the link of the appscript documentation for the stuff that you mean please is just that i don´t have enough experience with appscript.

Comment: Here are the useful references: [Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview), [Bound Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), [onOpen trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene), [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet). Just a quick background, you can create functions which will include formula in a specified range  in your Sheets that could be triggered/called when you open the document. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCBtsQGtzoQ